# undefined variable in php sendmail script

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I've checked the forum but haven't been able to fins an aswer to this problem. I get an error message saying "**Notice: Undefined variable: errors in C:\xampp\htdocs....**"

My code:

```
    <?php
   if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $subject = $_POST["subject"];
   $message = $_POST["message"];

   $errors = array();

   $email_matcher = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*" .

   "@" .

   "[a-z0-9-]+" .

   "(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/";

   if (preg_match($email_matcher, $email) == 0) {

     array_push($errors, "You did not enter a valid email address");
   }


   if (count($errors) == 0) {

    $to = "johnnyB@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = "[From My Web] " . $subject;
    $from = $name . " <" . $email . ">";
    $headers = "From: " . $from;
    header("location:thank_you.php");

    if (!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
      array_push($errors, "Mail failed to send.");
       }
      }
     }
```

Form Code Below

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>User Information</legend>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
<br />
<label for="pass">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" required/>
<br />
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required/>
<br />
<label for="cwid">CWID:</label>
<input type="text" name="cwid" id="cwid" required/>
<br />
<label for="comp">Complete:</label>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Registration'>
</fieldset>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Post your form. Most likely, your form elements are not named and/or contain typos/lettercase. Your conditional statement controls everything. `name="send"` if that's not in your form and the same for the others, there's the cause.

Comment: error in which line?

Comment: as above, post the **full** error message, and the **full** file that it relates to

Comment: i expect the problem is where you attempts to display the errors on the form, eg somewhere (outside of the if (isset($_POST["send"])) block in which $errors is defined, you attempt to access the non existant $errors variable. Without an edit, this is only a guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** (See added/modified PHP code further below about a missing errors array and `foreach` loop).

Since you have not provided your HTML form, the most likely reason is that your form elements are not named.

I am providing you with a sample HTML form that you can base yourself on and modify to suit, which I have tested with your PHP/mail function provided in your question.

```
<form method="POST" action="handler.php">

    Name: 
    <input type="text" name="name">

    <br>

    Email: 
    <input type="text" name="email">

    <br>

    Subject: 
    <input type="text" name="subject">

    <br>
    Message: <br>

    <textarea rows="6" name="message" cols="40"></textarea>

    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="send">

</form>
```

---

**Edit:** Modified PHP with an `foreach` error method.

```
<?php 

   if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $subject = $_POST["subject"];
   $message = $_POST["message"];

   $errors = array();


   $email_matcher = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*" .

   "@" .

   "[a-z0-9-]+" .

   "(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/";

   if (preg_match($email_matcher, $email) == 0) {

     array_push($errors, "You did not enter a valid email address");
   }


   if (count($errors) == 0) {

    $to = "email@example.com"; 
    $subject = "[From My Web] " . $subject;
    $from = $name . " <" . $email . ">";
    $headers = "From: " . $from;
    header("location:thank_you.php");


    if (!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
      array_push($errors, "Mail failed to send.");
       }
      }


     }

?>


<?php foreach($errors as $error):?>
    <p class="layer-content">
    <?php echo $error;?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Based on the error message, i expect his problem is where he attempts to display the errors on his form, eg somewhere (outside of the `if (isset($_POST["send"]))` block in which `$errors` is defined, he will attempt to access the non existant `$errors` variable

Comment: @user574632 +1 You stand at being correct there, for sure. Another thing OP isn't showing, is probable mix of JS and/or Ajax. I've provided the OP a sample form that worked with posted code. The OP will have to post a comment as to why it may not be working with my answer.

Comment: @user574632 The OP's error message doesn't outline the exact variable; which is vague. *I get an error message saying "`Notice: Undefined variable: errors in C:\xampp\htdocs....`"* - hard to say at this point, but what you said shouldn't be left out of the equation.

Comment: Im fairly sure that message suggests the specific variable, named `$errors` - if the variable was `$cat` it would read `Notice: Undefined variable: cat in C:\...` but this is all speculation without feedback from the op. I never understand why people post and leave

Comment: @user574632 I'm sure also at this point about what you said. I'm trying to replicate OP's problem, but am not being successful and trying to find an alternate solution. If I can't or find that I'm chasing after a ghost for too long, then I'll just delete my answer. I too don't understand when they leave, but people can be strange animals at times; I won't count myself out neither; I don't leave, I can just be strange; who isn't sometimes lol - *Cheers* and thanks for the feeback.

Comment: @user574632 I made an edit adding a `foreach` to/and below OP's code. Tested fine, see if you agree. I appreciate the feedback. Far as I can tell, OP's only checking for Email field.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Thanks a lot! Works great! I'm not sure exactly how you fixed it though ;-O

Comment: @rob75 You're welcome. I added `?>
<?php foreach($errors as $error):?>
    <p class="layer-content">
    <?php echo $error;?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach;?>` including the form, just in case.